# New contact shortcut

Tags: contacts, home-screen-shortcuts

Is there any way (besides Tasker) to create a new contact in one click? (For example: quick access to save a contact info during a call.)

Answer (score 0):

[Call Actions & Reminders](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Call-Actions-Reminders/com.movinapp.callactions) does offer this, amongst many other things:

> 1-click actions after a call:
>
> - Copy the call details in the system clipboard
> - Call back
> - Send an SMS
> - View the contact or add a new number to the contacts list
> - Send an email. In case the contact has an email, the application will use it
> - Share the contact details with its VCard if available. Id set the application can only share the details as plain text.
> - Make a Google search of the phone number, which may be helpful to research unknown numbers
> - Create a reminder associated to the contact or phone number: [...]

[image: Call Actions & Reminders]
<sup>Screenshot during an ongoing call (click image for larger variant)</sup>

More details can be found behind above link :)